# flash movies looping with javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, movie

Ok this code works in Firefox but doesn't work in IE and Chrome. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var flashNumber = 0;
var items = 3;

films = new Array(items)
films[0] = "movies/animals1.swf";
films[1] = "movies/mammyblue2.swf";
films[2] = "movies/whitebird1.swf";

function rotate(){
holder = document.getElementById('content');
holderr = document.getElementById('contra');
flashNumber++;
if(flashNumber == items)
    flashNumber = 0;
holder.src = films[flashNumber];
holderr.value = films[flashNumber];
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<object width="400" height="300">
<param name="movie" value="movies/animals1.swf" id="contra">
<embed src = "movies/animals1.swf" name="content" id="content" 
width="400" height="300">
</embed>
</object>
<input type="button" value="next" onclick="rotate();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have put button with onclick calling the rotate function. In FF it changes the swf clips,in Chrome the flash movies aren't appearing and in IE the next button does nothing.

Comment: That's because you're not changing the `param`'s value and you're missing the `movies/` directory in it as well.

Comment: still not working can't change the param value using getElementById by assigning id to the param tag

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to change the parameters when flash is loaded.

You can delete current flash object and create new, set it's new movie (for object tag) and src (for embed tag). This method useful when you need to display unknown or protected flash movies (you are not an author).

Or

Use External Interface for communication between flash and javascript. Pass new movie filename to flash and restart it in action script. This method useful when you can change your movie clips yourself.
More about pass data to flash from javascript:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14253.html#main_javascript

http://www.afcomponents.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1690

http://www.afcomponents.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1426

Comment: creating and deleting flash object works but I can't close the embed tag via javascript and this makes the script useless in IE here is the function: var container = document.getElementById('container');
  
   document.body.appendChild(container);
   container.appendChild(obj);
   obj.appendChild(par);
   obj.appendChild(emb);

Comment: It's not clear to me. Could you post full source code? Current version.